# Difference between request.timeout.ms and timeout.ms properties of Kafka producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Refering the [kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#consumerconfigs), a Kafka message producer configuration have `request.timeout.ms` and `timeout.ms` properties. Reading the description of these two properties, I am not able clearly distinguish between them.

Can anyone explain the difference using small example.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`request.timeout.ms` is the timeout configured on the client side. It says that the client is going to wait this much time for the server to respond to a request.

`timeout.ms` is the timeout configured on the leader in the Kafka cluster. This is the timeout on the server side. For example if you have set the acks setting to all, the server will not respond until all of its followers have sent a response back to the leader. The leader will wait `timeout.ms` amount of time for all the followers to respond.

So client sends a request to the server (leader). Based on the acks setting, the server will either wait or respond back to the client. `timeout.ms` is the amount of time the leader waits for its followers whereas `request.timeout.ms` is the amount of time the client waits for the server(leader).

Comment: by this logic can we say that request.timeout.ms = timeout.ms + network overhead?

Comment: In a way, you can say that.

Answer (score 7):

They are both used for the common underlying network client, meaning the max amount of time for awaiting a response from the request, although timeout.ms is marked as 'Deprecated'. Actually, timeout.ms is only used on the producer side, and request.timeout.ms can be defined for both client(including producer and consumer) and server(for replicating threads).

Kafka recommends that user specify request.timeout.ms instead of timeout.ms

Comment: can you provide link of some official documentation where it is mentioned that timeout.ms is deprecated.

Comment: Official document has not been updated but you can find it in the source code. Actually, if you specify timeout.ms, you will get a warning saying :

"timeout.ms config is deprecated and will be removed soon. Please use request.timeout.ms"

Comment: I am referring to Kafka 0.10.1.0